# Approximating conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request

Suppose I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$.

What methods exists for approximating the function (conditional expectation) $$m(X)=E(Y|X)?$$ Is there a general answer to this question? I know that if e.g. $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normally distributed, then $m(X)$ is a line in $X$; but is there some general way of approximating $m(X)$? For example, for a real function $f(x)$ of a single variable $x$ we have the quite general result of knowing when we may Taylor expand $f$ around some point $x_0$.

Comment: Without any further assumptions on the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$, I don't see how a quick method could be relied on for even an approximate conditional expectation.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression